# How does CursorAdapter recycle Views in ListView?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-cursoradapter

I know that `BaseAdapter` has a mechanism in order to recycle Views in a `ListView` for efficiency. But how does it work in `CursorAdapter` exactly? Is it the same thing? I haven't really found any documentation on this. The closest there was is with the World of ListView's google IO video, but that doesn't take into account CursorAdapter. Any advice on the matter would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

The `getView()` method is responsible for recycling the row views(it's the same thing as for a non cursor based adapter, just that it delegates the row construction and data binding to two different methods) and for moving the `Cursor` to the correct position.

Comment: I'm gonna be honest and say I didn't really know where to get the source code, or rather just look at it. Thanks for the link. I will read it through.